# Creating "active" dropdown menu item

Tags: reactjs

I have a functioning "dropdown menu" - clicking on "menu item" routes to a different component. I want to change the style of "dropdown menu item" after clicking, so the next time "dropdown menu" opens, "item" that has been clicked has a different look - indicating active state.

Behavior I want to replicate can be observed on the page I'm re-writing in  React : [code-learning.uk](https://code-learning.uk/) , after clicking on item from black menu dropdown button (USEFUL ST), "menu item" changes color to blue.

**DropdownMenu**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { MenuItemContentSchool } from "./sub-components/MenuItemContentSchool"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const DropdownMenu = () => {

  const [click, setClick] = useState("");  
  const handleClick = () => setClick("hide-menu");

  return (
    <div className={`${click}`}>
    {MenuItemContentSchool.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <Link to={item.link} onClick={handleClick} key={item.title}>
          {item.title}
        </Link>
      )
    } )}

</div>
  )
}
export default DropdownMenu
```

**NaviMain.js**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import DropdownMenu from "./DropdownMenu";

const NaviMain = () => {

    const [disp, setDisp] = useState(false);
    const hoverOn = () => setDisp(true)
    const hoverOff = () => setDisp(false)       

  return (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li onMouseEnter={hoverOn} onMouseLeave={hoverOff}>
                <a>school</a>
                { disp && <DropdownMenu /> }
            </li>            
        </ul>    
    </nav>
  )
}
export default NaviMain
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NaviMain from "./components/NaviMain";
import VerticalAlign from "./pages/VerticalAlign";
import Flexbox from "./pages/Flexbox";

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NaviMain />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/verticalalign" element={<VerticalAlign />} />
            <Route path="/flexbox" element={<Flexbox/>} />
          </Routes>              
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**MenuItemContentSchool**

```
export const MenuItemContentSchool = [
    {
        title:"v align",
        link:"/verticalalign",
    },
    {
        title:"flexbox",
        link:"/flexbox",
    },
]
```

Comment: Please let us know where you hold the details of which menu-item was clicked most-recently in the dropdown. This information will help in setting a different class for the specific item that was last-clicked. That, hopefully, should achieve the expected functionality.

Comment: Not sure the question was about this, but details of every menu-item can be found in "MenuItemContentSchool" component, (just posted it in my question).

Comment: my idea was to add a class to`<Link>` through new `useState` in `handleclick`, which would set a new class and pass it dynamically. But that didn't work.

Comment: _Behavior I want to replicate can be observed_ ... _after clicking on item_ ... _"menu item" changes color to blue_ <--- this can be achieved by knowing which "menu item" was clicked most-recently. If one needs to de-couple the state from the menu-items, then we may use the `index` to know which menu-item was clicked (`onClick` may be used to set-state to store/save the `index`). Then, use the saved `index` to switch the style/class.

Comment: i could get the item through `e.target` . and set the index, after click. It would be easy in vanilla JS, but in React - how to use this to switch the style?

Answer (score 0):

Do a check to see if the current page matches the items link, then add a class to the link for that item.

something like:

```
   const activeClass = window.location.pathname.startsWith(item.link) ? "isActive" : "";

<Link to={item.link} onClick={handleClick} key={item.title} className={activeClass}>
  {item.title}
</Link>
```

Comment: if that logic could have been implemented inside `className` in`<Link>` , that would seem to might be effective,  after `.map` . Because i dont see how `activeClass` could be passed from `handleClick` - every `<Link>` would have this class

Comment: you can declare active class inside the map function:

`{MenuItemContentSchool.map((item, index) => {

const activeClass = window.location.pathname.startsWith(item.link) ? "isActive" : "";
      return (
        <Link to={item.link} onClick={handleClick} key={item.title} className={activeClass}>
          {item.title}
        </Link>
      )
    }`

Comment: seems legit, I have to try this. There is a similar solution as well, using `<NavLink>` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71730313/creating-logic-inside-classname-active-class